# Create local login after openAuth registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an MVC4 application and have implemented OpenAuth Login. When a user decides to log in/ register with an external account. e.g. Google the user is taken to the Google login. Upon successful login the application asks the user to register the returned email.

Now when I try to login with the email address locally it fails. Is there a way that when the user logs in successfully with Google then the application also creates a local user account?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there is already functionality to do this. the Manage action of the Account controller allows the creation of a local account. the CreateAccount() method assumes that the user exists in UserProfile and creates a Membership acount for that username